# How can I compile a .jjt file in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, svg

I'm trying to use [SVG Salamander](https://svgsalamander.java.net/)'s source code in an Eclipse project. However, I can't compile/run anything, because in the `com.kitfox.svg.animation` package, there's a file with extension ".jjt". I've never encountered this kind of file before, and it doesn't appear to be valid Java syntax, yet a lot of the project depends on a class defined within it and imports it as if it were a regular class. What do I do with this file? How do I compile it and use the class within it?

Comment: `.jjt` is the typical ectension for a JJTree grammar file, which requires JavaCC to compile it into Java code.

Comment: But why do you need to compile the code yourself rather than just using the pre-built JAR as a library?

Comment: @IanRoberts It's just personal preference. After all, the project is open-source, so I want to try to use the source.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ian Roberts' suggestions:

- `sudo apt-get install javacc`
- Open the appropriate workspace directory in a terminal
- `javacc YourFile.jjt`
- Add the generated Java files to the project